# SET game in javascript

Tags: javascript

"SET", not to be confused with the data-structure is a card game in which player try to find a combination of 3 cards.

Each cards have 4 attributes: color, number, shape, and filling-pattern. A legal set must either have to contain all variant of a attribute (all color) or just one variant(say red). Therefore, any set that have exactly 2 variant of attribute is therefore always be a illegal set.

[a more detailed rule can be find here](https://www.setgame.com/sites/default/files/instructions/SET%20INSTRUCTIONS%20-%20ENGLISH.pdf)

here's my implementation of the game. It's my first js program so it is not the most pretty thing.

**constants**

To start things off I create a set that would contain all the answers in int. They are all precomputed using python. My though process is this: a collection of cards is a cluster of information (sequence doesn't matter). Therefore I give each card a corresponding prime number and calculate all the legal set. For example card #1, #2, and #3 is a set. and their corresponding prime is 2, 3, and 5. Thus you will find 30 in the answer set. By doing so i can be confident that each set would have a distinct value. and thanks to math 2*3*5 = 5*3*2 saving memory space. We need first 81 primes to verify user input so I also include that(ln2)

**functions**

*shuffle* takes an array and randomize the order of it. (I find this on the internet)

*drawBoard* takes no argument and draw the board using the first 12 value of the deck poping them and create appropriate objects.

*reload* takes no argument and initialize the deck

*fetchNew* a helper function that takes id as argument and update new information to that object accordance to the deck. Create a blank card + disable the object when no more card in the deck.

*checkSet* a helper function that takes no argument and checks if the selecitons of 3 cards by the user(selected) contains a legal-set.

*updateState* the heart of the program. Actively update the board when input were made. call checkset when needed.

How can I improve my code? Maybe organize everything into a class so there's less global values(deck and selections)? Or perhaps using a framework instead of just pure-JS? I am newbie to js and I don't know what the best practice is! Thank you for reading and answering.

```js
let all_answer = new Set([192515, 2529283, 6930437, 4827143, 407563, 1630219, 7518223, 1200149, 1660949, 2703383, 7243799, 5337109, 512029, 30, 856097, 38947, 5742629, 30597157, 2021417, 3534889, 829483, 2969641, 6428717, 59438, 13041709, 2955313, 8466481, 1079347, 1779763, 10295, 2218039, 1916983, 4667447, 5228603, 5648441, 39110717, 55361, 3127361, 37140553, 6649931, 30900299, 4700237, 4038733, 2658389, 2713687, 32857, 9363547, 1943647, 299105, 1476707, 2449511, 475241, 4698217, 37234793, 39489641, 36016237, 520303, 819313, 1138801, 53363, 2678899, 3553393, 4317301, 6410359, 14457, 551033, 3305593, 38635643, 182397, 3532927, 38338687, 1034371, 7934083, 8626309, 4874371, 2123911, 5308549, 4094089, 311435, 3750029, 9955469, 10385, 22673, 497809, 3672211, 19710101, 36368531, 602263, 3870871, 227481, 733337, 866459, 7422109, 1925281, 26789, 2646181, 5187751, 12112039, 612527, 5195951, 36161711, 39091, 2054323, 3532979, 8374, 6656179, 4733107, 5183669, 2369723, 2138299, 51389, 577727, 3889343, 2474177, 2265283, 8636611, 774341, 1925317, 6738119, 4833481, 71882, 250061, 581837, 6351, 2044109, 2740429, 5587151, 3590359, 59119831, 1435867, 40374491, 36495581, 768223, 20705, 3395809, 573667, 116967, 59590891, 238, 243951, 123119, 55537, 3002609, 11438321, 399605, 4141303, 534779, 3240187, 934141, 5382397, 7461119, 5566721, 3217667, 43456771, 4212997, 10502, 5243141, 34377991, 2500877, 2998543, 6633743, 1153297, 3733777, 1022227, 1476883, 2363671, 24857, 190747, 34355483, 1878301, 3602717, 3424543, 36288797, 104737, 76067, 5777701, 36802853, 7979303, 3488041, 985387, 1542449, 3385649, 3283253, 1100087, 379195, 4700477, 514367, 1610047, 2132287, 2935103, 829763, 4034879, 4260163, 1780039, 36475207, 3664201, 5427529, 86349, 139598, 178509, 909649, 231763, 1515859, 3264853, 4127059, 39259, 36639067, 1958239, 2416991, 14691, 84323, 1040741, 5357923, 1470823, 4041061, 891241, 4473187, 3082603, 874861, 2435441, 3043699, 217461, 20914549, 20855, 6304121, 440699, 2556283, 12669, 3058043, 34111867, 5572993, 10068353, 12022147, 2470277, 49543, 4479367, 2736521, 35926409, 1483147, 4094353, 2111479, 36579737, 80282, 6703517, 63043997, 3641761, 4112803, 3897763, 2916773, 5652901, 450983, 328105, 4526, 6920623, 5548463, 151985, 43821487, 3897779, 1051063, 59831, 117177, 418235, 2054587, 3656123, 7393723, 5261759, 1833409, 4424129, 9095621, 36145609, 6603, 3633611, 115149, 4303307, 926159, 7973333, 3723737, 35135963, 4639199, 36250079, 848353, 483, 1591781, 2638309, 4108777, 7205353, 36628973, 494, 358895, 33263, 219633, 150002, 1104371, 2609647, 520693, 1894897, 6541813, 3973621, 506, 1184251, 6345211, 1204733, 9296383, 37323263, 2603521, 3770881, 752131, 1616387, 7160323, 14457349, 30857731, 27145, 158218, 3273227, 4264457, 2091533, 7645711, 1374739, 3279379, 1581589, 36256277, 4166167, 5810711, 10832407, 4987417, 4893211, 1376797, 57889, 1262113, 80417, 9957923, 4526629, 115238, 5536291, 35269153, 131629, 858671, 11174447, 80434, 39479, 3273271, 2742841, 4686397, 4817473, 113221, 164422, 1659461, 7479877, 5356103, 11749957, 33796681, 1245773, 612943, 1710673, 3953239, 148058, 8430173, 2259553, 30487139, 1888871, 457327, 627, 4950643, 2646647, 6984311, 36403831, 36399739, 1872511, 1796737, 2474627, 3467911, 3818119, 6599303, 1927819, 133774, 217743, 1942159, 41857681, 164498, 5747347, 36289171, 5296789, 663, 58007, 665, 8858, 795289, 1499803, 723613, 2056861, 8323739, 3343001, 123554, 7215781, 5583527, 27307, 4942507, 2495153, 35674801, 1796791, 1542839, 762553, 3859129, 6777539, 1606343, 461513, 2597587, 3467987, 5378771, 66263, 8721113, 4715231, 5280479, 2689763, 4190947, 13029, 2851559, 3922663, 9954023, 37313257, 4807403, 500461, 158446, 2806511, 1239793, 2634481, 3193591, 2951929, 3584761, 244479, 6753023, 234241, 59380481, 1417987, 4045571, 4000517, 2347783, 3816199, 23305, 36813577, 4442891, 486157, 549647, 936721, 5511953, 3795731, 3142423, 7858967, 1215259, 3572509, 140065, 37903141, 371495, 2773801, 1948459, 2315051, 1415983, 21855023, 1577777, 21359407, 6736693, 78647, 1792823, 2423609, 2911039, 189249, 582467, 1147721, 5450569, 408397, 242511, 1260367, 3960823, 3361619, 2581333, 1958743, 37905239, 1268573, 3668831, 2337631, 1921891, 2528101, 3822443, 4066159, 2358131, 7396217, 361339, 957307, 426877, 1624957, 478079, 4160383, 2708353, 146306, 123778, 2982787, 2308997, 5630851, 2546567, 103309, 1958797, 4711309, 3007379, 2937749, 3091349, 811927, 36268951, 3261343, 4811683, 5579683, 3464101, 935, 1520551, 478121, 123819, 82861, 8627117, 6929327, 46179247, 33708979, 3214261, 2954167, 3435449, 369595, 2966461, 4115389, 3591103, 7162817, 1649603, 463813, 7015367, 2546633, 5587913, 1506251, 21087179, 3865549, 3703757, 4834253, 431057, 3859409, 2950097, 1700821, 12205013, 8125399, 2116567, 1940441, 2821081, 2069467, 2399197, 34710493, 248799, 3240929, 7805923, 9118693, 3748837, 1001, 52207, 3877873, 1698803, 8315893, 4314103, 30999547, 42302461, 46079, 211967, 1776641, 2184191, 2038787, 5555203, 5635073, 32318467, 848903, 56327, 4264969, 38710279, 2016271, 3173393, 5188627, 3770359, 185365, 599063, 2673689, 4414489, 2016283, 2501659, 3714077, 1317919, 2954279, 2075687, 3716137, 36580393, 2315311, 5366831, 226353, 316465, 3415091, 36256819, 549941, 38233141, 668729, 21345343, 78913, 3167303, 351307, 36756557, 3710033, 87123, 2382931, 1936469, 2522197, 2171993, 3320923, 3963997, 5764189, 3150943, 2593889, 2706533, 54379, 3077231, 969841, 2329721, 2309243, 144509, 347261, 37039231, 44161, 35890307, 5254, 1703047, 3273863, 2081929, 4850827, 44227723, 1524877, 6169741, 4093069, 68719771, 2225309, 5954719, 1234081, 3394723, 201895, 3777703, 1934507, 353455, 1367221, 490679, 994487, 4670647, 5631161, 208059, 212155, 38077, 4549819, 36830393, 13505, 10114241, 5315777, 35742919, 4785353, 40139, 44239, 730319, 556241, 834769, 2168017, 169174, 5170391, 920803, 1066211, 5135593, 19691, 2108651, 1715437, 2460907, 3237103, 4562941, 6132979, 7406837, 595193, 8414459, 2858237, 5186813, 3595519, 2311427, 6384899, 7429, 4738309, 1312007, 2080007, 4105481, 7437, 400655, 654607, 3644689, 58642, 3337487, 4617491, 41553173, 9494, 240919, 35211409, 402715, 5575963, 435485, 4705567, 36181279, 3693857, 5279009, 34352419, 2839847, 7871783, 103721, 3685673, 668971, 3308843, 3697961, 2090293, 2229559, 10796347, 492863, 39605567, 4101443, 791879, 2518343, 4056391, 1862989, 5162317, 3321169, 3810641, 3824981, 167254, 4754777, 6229337, 1498459, 30704987, 36474211, 87397, 2882917, 5279081, 4056427, 13677, 392557, 572783, 6868339, 210295, 1351033, 3872123, 4560251, 736637, 1664381, 2006399, 2256253, 3280253, 3151231, 5561723, 1484167, 5133703, 66953, 4455817, 5354891, 513421, 36439439, 2057617, 3419539, 9794963, 492949, 42179987, 56729, 1979801, 249243, 4019611, 777631, 89503, 140705, 3921311, 77221, 8418727, 3831209, 265643, 1480111, 2626999, 5014967, 2506169, 36416951, 785851, 1646011, 2784703, 1009091, 21093827, 30149, 31204807, 5053901, 1495, 1584599, 5146073, 1852897, 1285601, 6825443, 679397, 2997733, 277991, 3665381, 21995, 3548651, 198129, 6018547, 42845683, 10165751, 353785, 138746, 2539003, 36472313, 3622397, 37283321, 2219519, 3091967, 7466497, 25456133, 398855, 1703431, 669191, 4124171, 2715149, 3657229, 1244689, 2321941, 2506261, 3409429, 351769, 974363, 1510939, 1119773, 1302047, 4271647, 5922337, 4273697, 56867, 2422307, 63017, 1994281, 2444843, 8656429, 37969453, 26159, 4329007, 5748271, 3448373, 3188279, 183867, 3681851, 42559, 59147839, 3565123, 3700297, 75338, 5418571, 5111369, 8080973, 1402447, 116313, 3763801, 5711449, 2725469, 106079, 3636833, 3014243, 35460709, 1818217, 4208233, 46699, 36095593, 30317, 2655857, 401011, 2553461, 796279, 3743351, 38706809, 1277567, 2508421, 525959, 34441, 24205, 257677, 1369741, 3790477, 8232589, 4312717, 532117, 1638037, 2614933, 153242, 21159581, 2397859, 5605027, 411301, 124582, 5428903, 35165863, 3247787, 34897579, 528047, 35573423, 1222321, 153266, 3303089, 8689333, 1257143, 1875641, 5334713, 3436219, 8289979, 5627581, 36312761, 1543873, 3823297, 2727619, 3862211, 2657989, 83654, 186055, 3362503, 2436809, 972491, 2754251, 2127571, 54998, 4028119, 5598937, 29333209, 77531, 51881689, 2293469, 4953821, 4202207, 681697, 2764513, 30387937, 59817697, 2631397, 59857921, 2160359, 4765421, 12199661, 2000627, 2604787, 2942707, 7126771, 48887, 7274231, 5709563, 59369213, 2817791, 847619, 37193477, 1404679, 6733577, 2381579, 1500943, 7954, 48919, 7393049, 83738, 6950681, 36519709, 497441, 3510049, 755491, 810787, 3235619, 59344673, 112423, 5312297, 7143209, 2576173, 3886, 7182127, 2389811, 399157, 2185013, 849719, 46903, 3227449, 2408249, 913211, 4230971, 7262011, 4071233, 530243, 6786883, 14151, 4570957, 22351, 3047249, 5521237, 3809111, 4716377, 18181979, 3610463, 5465953, 2279269, 35540837, 5322599, 5875561, 36351853, 38094701, 554863, 833393, 2246513, 37625713, 2570101, 3647351, 6098809, 970619, 2416507, 1634173, 2404223, 5040001, 391045, 1963909, 2191237, 5264023, 571273, 649097, 122763, 40843, 7530379, 10126, 49039, 1863569, 3590033, 1750933, 3299221, 583573, 44957, 5625757, 2889631, 3600287, 56364961, 2740147, 6965177, 2072507, 3553211, 23205823, 5484481, 243651, 1198019, 292805, 36114371, 1361863, 4702151, 2809801, 587723, 36595661, 225231, 3731407, 4470737, 11644879, 1759187, 4487123, 4827091, 3272663, 36175831, 2932697, 75739, 1720283, 3499997, 5369821, 6094813, 4159457, 4196323, 3565547, 21880811, 86001, 765941, 280567, 1898489, 3291133, 3657727
]);
let primes = [
  2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419
];


function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}


function drawBoard() {
    mainGrid = document.getElementById("main");
  z = 0;
  y = 0;
  while (z < 3) {
    y = 0;
    while (y < 4) {
      x = deck.pop();
      newButton = document.createElement("button");
      newButton.setAttribute('id', '(' + z + ',' + y + ')');
      newButton.setAttribute('repr', x - 1);
      newButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'updateState(this.id);');


      newImg = document.createElement("img");
      newImg.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.setgame.com/sites/all/modules/setgame_set/assets/images/new/' + x + '.png');
      newImg.setAttribute('alt', x);
      //newImg.setAttribute('width','22.5%');
      newImg.setAttribute('width', '215');


      newButton.appendChild(newImg);


      mainGrid.appendChild(newButton);
      y += 1;
    }
    lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
    mainGrid.appendChild(lineBreak);
    z += 1
  }

}


function reload() {
  deck = Array(81).fill(1).map((_, i) => i + 1);
  selected = [];



  shuffle(deck);
  mainGrid = document.getElementById("main");
  while (mainGrid.lastChild) {
    mainGrid.removeChild(mainGrid.lastChild);
  }

  drawBoard();
}


function fetch_new(id) {
  let el = document.getElementById(id)
  el.removeChild(el.lastChild);
  let x = deck.pop()

  if (x == undefined) {
    el.setAttribute('disabled', 1);
    newImg = document.createElement("img");
    newImg.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.setgame.com/sites/all/modules/setgame_set/assets/images/new/empty_card.gif');
  } else {
    el.setAttribute('repr', x - 1);
    newImg = document.createElement("img");
    newImg.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.setgame.com/sites/all/modules/setgame_set/assets/images/new/' + x + '.png');
  }
  newImg.setAttribute('alt', x);
  newImg.setAttribute('width', '215');


  el.appendChild(newImg)

}


function checkSet() {

  let el = 0;
  let x = 0
  let newImg = 0;
  let y = 0;

  let sum = 1;
  while (y < 3) {
    el = document.getElementById(selected[y]);
    sum *= primes[el.getAttribute("repr")];
    el.lastChild.setAttribute('style', 'filter: brightness(100%);');
    y += 1;
  }

  if (all_answer.has(sum)) {
    message = "good job! you find a set!";

  } else {
    selected = [];
    message = "very close but, not a set";
    return
  }
  y = 0;
  while (y < 3) {
    fetch_new(selected.pop());
    y += 1;
  }
  return
}


function updateState(id) {

  if (selected.includes(id)) {
    selected = selected.filter(function(item) {
      return item !== id
    })
    el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.lastChild.setAttribute('style', 'filter: brightness(100%);')
  } else {
    //let el = document.getElementById(id);
    //el.removeChild(el.lastChild);
    selected.push(id);
    el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.lastChild.setAttribute('style', 'filter: brightness(80%);')


  }
  message = "";
  if (selected.length == 3) {
    checkSet();
  }
  span = document.getElementById("history");
  txt = document.createTextNode(selected);
  if (span.lastChild){
    span.removeChild(span.lastChild);  
  }
  span.appendChild(txt);
  span = document.getElementById("message");
  txt = document.createTextNode(message);
  if (span.lastChild){
    span.removeChild(span.lastChild);
  }
  span.appendChild(txt);
}


reload();
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
<br>
you selcted: <span id="history"></span>
<br>
<span id="message"></span>

<br>
<br>
<button onclick=reload()>new game</button>
```